# Rename user interface headers in VS 2010 setup project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

Does anyone know whether it's possible to change the header text in a Visual Studio 2010 setup project?I have a custom banner bitmap and sometimes the afore mentioned header text goes over the banner image so I'm looking for a way to completely remove it or rename it to something shorter.

[image: Setup Project header text]

Comment: Don't use VS setup projects, they will always give you trouble. Use WiX instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the wix installer to solve the problem :

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146626/Extending-Visual-Studio-Setup-Project

this will be useful

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: ***Why*** will it "be useful"?